# mysql запрос не проходит из-за символа

Tags: php, mysql

В тексте имеется символ 
Как его и подобные можно отфильтровать средствами php?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы действительно хотите удалить все расширенные символы UTF то сделайте это регеспом - разрешив только буквы и допустимые знаки(!@#$%^&...)

Символ в кодировке UTF8. Настройте  `mysql` и `php` на эту кодировку и тогда любые расширенные символы будут сохранятся нормально.
PHP: В начале скрипта. Ваша библиотека БД будет отличатся, но смысл остается тем же, указать чарсет.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8');
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
$db = new SafeMySQL(
    array(
        'host' => $dbhost,          
        'user' => $dbuser,
        'pass' => $dbpasswd,
        'db'   => $dbname,
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4'
    )
);
```

Не делайте тексты sql запроса содержащие переменные, используйте placeholder.

Comment: Во-первых, utf8 НЕ поддерживает расширенные символы.  Для расширенных надо utf8mb4. Во-вторых, не `$db->query('SET NAMES "utf8"');` а `'db'   => $dbname, 'charset' => 'utf8mb4')`. В-третьих, с чего вы взяли что автор пользуется этой библиотекой?

Comment: Библиотеку взял из своего кода - автор вопроса сам заменит на свою. Почему-то у меня работают расширенные символы без  mb4

Comment: да, и в-четвертных,  `<meta charset="utf-8">` - это абсолютно бессмысленное телодвжение

Comment: Я отредактирую ответ в соответствии с вашими комментариями или вы напишете свой?

Comment: лучше отредактируйте